# Event which occurs when form is focused

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms first is frmBase and second is frmBalloon.I alter the focus of both forms that first frmBase is shown then frmBalloon is shown(frmBase is not visible)and then again frmBase is shown.Now I have need of event that occurs first frmBase loads and then again when it shows after frmBalloon becomes not visible.

So I have need of event that occurs when form becomes focused.......

Comment: Are you switching between these two forms one by one using a button on each form that opens the another?

Comment: If you are opening/showing the form using ShowDialog() everytime then the Form_Load event can be used. How are you switching between the forms?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is [`Form.Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) what you're after?

My reason for suggesting this rather than `GotFocus` is that the form *itself* doesn't get focus if the focus changes from one form to a control on a different form. Here's a sample app:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        Button button = new Button
        {
            Location = new Point(0, 30),
            Text = "New form"
        };
        button.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            string name = tb.Text;
            Form f = new Form();
            f.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = name });
            f.Activated += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine("Activated: " + name);
            f.GotFocus += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine("GotFocus: " + name);
            f.Show();
            f.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Location = new Point(0, 30) });
        };

        Form master = new Form { Controls = { tb, button } };
        Application.Run(master);
    }
}
```

(Build this as a console app - that's where the output goes.)

Put some name in the text box and click "new form" - then do it again. Now click between the text boxes on the new form - you'll see the `Activated` event is getting fired, but not `GotFocus`.

Comment: No it does not work for mine because I want a event that occurs only when it focused..

Comment: When would it be activated without getting focus?

Comment: Hi Jon. Im curious, does the Activated event get fired each time you do anything on your form? If my form has got focus and I click on it multiple times does the Activate event get fired for each click?

Comment: @Chibbles: You'd have to test to make sure, but I believe it's only when it wasn't previously active.

Comment: `Activated` fires only when the form gets focus only once, not when you do anything on your form, just tested.

Comment: @JaydeepKarena: I'm not sure what you mean by "when you do anything on your form". I've just tested too, and switching between different forms triggered Activated each time.

Comment: Sir I do anything means moving focus from one control to another on a single form, so happy that `THE JON SKEET` replied to my comment

Comment: @Jaydeep: Yes, it wouldn't trigger for that - but I don't think that's what the question was asking about.

Answer (score 2):

What about the [GotFocus event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)?

Note that the GotFocus event on Control (from which Form is derived, so it applies here) is marked with the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx), passing a value of false to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.browsableattribute.aspx), so it is **not** visible in the properties window.

You should add the event handler manually in code *outside* of the designer-generated code.

Comment: Is it in event list of property window ??

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Form.GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) event.

Comment: Is it in event list of property window ??

Comment: Yes, it works for form. It should be in the event list, but you can always code it directly: `myForm.GotFocus += event_handler;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know five years ago, but nowadays:

[image]

The `Enter` event does the job.

Comment: Focus and Enter are different things. `Enter` when mouse gets entered in control area. `Focus` when control becomes active.