# Shortening division ratio

Tags: c#, division

I have done this for my division code, and instead of the numbers turning out like 10.55555 or 2.55555, how can it be shortened to 10.555 and 2.555

```
decimal d = numericUpDown1.Value / numericUpDown2.Value;
label1.Text = "Ratio: " + d.ToString();
```

Comment: Why a timer? The inputs probably have a `Changed` event of some sort. Listen to that event and recalculate when it's fired.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a timer, I would just like it automatic. Any other method is fine, but tips or suggestions? @ChrisSinclair

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979213/event-which-occurs-when-form-is-focused here is a good solution for your problem.

Comment: How denominator and numerator change? How much time they change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
decimal d = numericUpDown1.Value / numericUpDown2.Value ;
label1.Text = string.Format( "Ratio: {0}" ,
                Math.Round(d,3) ,
                MidpointRounding.ToEven
                ) ;
```

Or

```
decimal d = numericUpDown1.Value / numericUpDown2.Value ;
label1.Text = string.Format( "Ratio: {0:0.000}" ,
                Math.Round(d,3) ,
                MidpointRounding.ToEven
                ) ;
```

Comment: Yes! The second one is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!